# Serial output from arduino to php(localhost, usb port connection)

Tags: php, arduino, serial-communication

I'm currently working on a design project. I am kind of new to arduino. In my project im using php to call different methods on the arduion. The problem is how can i get data from the arduino to my php page? In my arduion code i have a counter and a time i would like to "print" into the webpage. I have a MySQL database, and im using XAMPP.
Do you guys have any solutions or recommendations ? what kind of codes should I write ? if you can post the code I will be appreciated.

Thanks you, Angil.. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what operating system are you using?

In case of Windows:
Download [PHP serial](https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial)

In case of (most) linux distros, use PHP serial too,

For debian (ubuntu, turnkey, etc.), you are going to have to add the `www-data` user to the `dialout` group. For info on this, check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58119/changing-permissions-on-serial-port) on the ubuntu forum.